# R, arrow: How to read .fwf format in R using arrow

Tags: r, apache-arrow, read.fwf, read-fwf

I have a data that is stored in several fixed width files (perhaps not fitting memory). It would be great to be able to read that using `arrow`.

```
p <- 'path_to_my_files'
# p contains: a.txt, b.txt, c.txt,.... all fwf
dic <- fread('fwf_dictionary.csv') # contains two columns varname and lenght indicating the variables (and position) in the fwf file
```

Is there a `read_fwf_arrow(path,dic)` function?  I imagine that a combination of `read_delim_arrow` (with a never occurring delimiter) with dplyr parsing for each column would be able to do the job, but I don't know how to loop through the variables in `dic` to extract each variable.

```
read_fwf_arrow <- function(path,dic){
    p %>% read_delimn_arrow(delim='#') %>% 
    loop_extracting_cols_that_can_run_on_arrow
}
```

Comment: I see no mention of "fwf" in arrow (I tried [site:arrow.apache.org/docs "fwf"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarrow.apache.org%2Fdocs+"fwf"), I think there's no arrow-native function for that. Are you able to read it in R and save as a different format (including parquet)?

Comment: That is the point. I am trying to avoid the traditional r reading of fwf (like `readr::read_fwf`)

Comment: Yeah, I get it ... sorry, I think this is a feature-request for arrow.

Comment: It's likely not difficult to use command-line (shell-script) utilities such as `cut` or `sed` or `awk` to convert a FWF file to CSV or similar that R/arrow *can* read lazily. It's not R, but it does allow you to (1) process the fwf efficiently, not in R; and (2) process the new file efficiently/lazily in R/arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is no fixed width reading in arrow. However we *can* make use of some `readr` functionality and how Datasets work. The process below involves creating an intermediate object, so not reading directly from the fixed width files. Sometimes that's ok, sometime not. Hopefully useful to you though:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(gdata) ## easiest way to create fixed width file
library(arrow)


## make a "big" fixed width dataset
write.fwf(x = quakes, file = "data.fwf", colnames = FALSE)

## create a temporary directory where you can write the chunks
tdir <- file.path(tempdir(), "arrow-tmp")
dir.create(tdir, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)

## callback function that reads in a chunk then converts that
## chunk into a parquet file
f <- function(x, pos) {
  d <- read_fwf(paste0(x, "\n"), fwf_widths(
    c(6, 6, 4, 4, 2),
    col_names = names(quakes)
  ))
  arrow::write_parquet(d, file.path(tdir, paste0("temp-", pos, ".parquet")))
}

## actually read in chunks 100 lines at a time
read_lines_chunked(file = "data.fwf", readr::SideEffectChunkCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 100)

## they are there
fs::dir_tree(tdir)
#> /var/folders/6f/c414rjlx2l512x7_80hp126c0000gn/T//RtmpHsOQmC/arrow-tmp
#> ├── temp-1.parquet
#> ├── temp-101.parquet
#> ├── temp-201.parquet
#> ├── temp-301.parquet
#> ├── temp-401.parquet
#> ├── temp-501.parquet
#> ├── temp-601.parquet
#> ├── temp-701.parquet
#> ├── temp-801.parquet
#> └── temp-901.parquet

## create a directory where you want your finished data to exist
tdir_real <- file.path(tempdir(), "arrow-real")

## open Dataset with chunked data then write it out again as parquet partitioned by station
arrow::open_dataset(tdir) %>%
  group_by(stations) %>%
  arrow::write_dataset(tdir_real)

fs::dir_tree(tdir_real)
#> /var/folders/6f/c414rjlx2l512x7_80hp126c0000gn/T//RtmpHsOQmC/arrow-real
#> ├── stations=0
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=1
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=2
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=3
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=4
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=5
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=6
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=7
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> ├── stations=8
#> │   └── part-0.parquet
#> └── stations=9
#>     └── part-0.parquet
```